# Unable to get resonse from import contacts sendgrid API using python

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-api-v2

Below is the call I am trying to make -
I used field mapping in below data -
data = {
"file_type": "csv",
"field_mappings": [
"_rf2_T",
"_rf0_T",
"_rf1_T",
"_rf10_T",
"w1_T",
"w45_T",
"w46_T",
"w44_T",
"w2_D",
"w43_T"
]
}
print("--data---",data)

```
response = sg.client.marketing.contacts.put(
    request_body=data
)

#print("--data---",data)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.body)
print(response.headers)
```

and getting below error
{'errors': [{'field': 'contacts', 'message': 'at least one contact is required'}]}

I am expecting upload url and header from api call